# How do I uninstall Java7 from macOs

Tags: java, jdk, jre

After April 2015, Oracle will no longer post updates of Java SE 7 to its public download sites. I am inclined to remove Java 1.7 and the JDK permanently from my Mac, if only I knew how to accomplish this in a clean way. [Oracle Java EOL announcement.](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml)

Comment: Did you see the [How do I uninstall Java on my Mac?](https://java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml) link on Oracle site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From : https://java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml

> Uninstall Oracle Java using the Terminal
>
> Note: To uninstall Java, you must have Administrator privileges and
>   execute the remove command either as root or by using the sudo tool.
>
> Remove one directory and one file (a symlink), as follows:
>
> Click on the Finder icon located in your dock
>
> Click on Go in the Finder menu
>
> Click on Utilities
>
> Double-click on the Terminal icon
>
> In the Terminal window Copy and Paste the commands below:

```
sudo rm -fr
 /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin



sudo rm -fr
 /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane



sudo rm -fr
 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
```

> Do not attempt to uninstall Java by removing the Java tools
>   from /usr/bin. This directory is part of the system software and any
>   changes will be reset by Apple the next time you perform an update of
>   the OS.